# Detect if page is on experience editor Sitecore 9 via Javascript?

Tags: experience-editor, presentation

Ok, i see many examples of this online but none seems to work, maybe those examples are for older Sitecore. I simply want to detect if the user is on regular site view or if they are on experience editor using some JS. I was messing with console and saw this method `Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.ExperienceEditor.length` but it always return 0. I saw many examples with c#/razor but interested in js for now.

Answer (score 8):

```
var isPageEditor = function(){
    return !!(Sitecore && Sitecore.PageModes && Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor);
};
 
if(isPageEditor()) {
    // Write your logic here
}
```

Here are some more details:

https://itsmycode.com/how-to-detect-page-editor-mode-in-sitecore-through-code/

https://mattneil.co.uk/2016/12/08/detect-sitecore-page-modes/

Comment: i actually  tried this but on regular view i am getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Sitecore is not defined
    at pageEditorMode"" it works on editor mode . Basically i am trying to disable sticky nav on experiance editor. i put a try catch around like below to solve for now. Is there a better way to solve this? . i am putting code as one of the answer

Comment: Needs a type check
 (typeof Sitecore !== "undefined" && Sitecore && Sitecore.PageModes && Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor)

Answer (score 4):

This has worked for us. Note that we adjusted our layout view to add the `sc-edit-mode` CSS class to the body, which also helps identify Experience Editor mode.

## `isPageEditor()` function

```
function isPageEditor() {
    return (!!((typeof Sitecore !== "undefined") && (typeof Sitecore.PageModes !== "undefined") && (typeof Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor !== "undefined")) || (document.body && document.body.getAttribute("class") === "sc-edit-mode"));
};
```

## View modifications

```
<html class="@(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor ? "sc-edit-mode" : string.Empty)">
```

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.ExperienceEditor is an internal EE function that you can`t call direct to return true/false.

As @Vlad mentioned, in EE you can check it with

```
var isExperienceEditor = !!(Sitecore && Sitecore.PageModes && Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor)
```

(it means that all these objects are not undefined == you are in EE).

But 'Sitecore' namespace doesn`t exist in Normal page mode and as a workaround you can use your custom global variable that is initialized in a layout of your page (with razor or aspx syntax)

```
<script>
    var isExperienceEditor = Json.Encode(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm using which works in **regular view** too (and no double bang (!!) or try/catch needed):

```
const isExperienceEditor = () => window.Sitecore && Sitecore.PageModes && Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to vlad lobagiu.   I tried vlad lobagiu answer but on regular view i am getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Sitecore is not defined at pageEditorMode"" it works on editor mode, i am guessing sitecore object is not available on published site(make sense) . Basically i am trying to disable sticky nav on experiance editor, I put a try catch around like below to solve for now. Is there a better way to solve this?

```
    try {
     // Sitecore global name space in page editor or preview mode
     var pageEditorMode = function () {
        return !!(Sitecore && Sitecore.PageModes && Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor);
     };

     if (pageEditorMode()) {
        console.log("Experience editor detected, not adding sticky white header")
     }
     else {
        function()

     }
  } catch (error) {
     if (error) {
                    function()

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of the two best answers here works well.

```
var isEditMode = function() { 
    return typeof Sitecore !== "undefined" && Sitecore 
        && Sitecore.PageModes && Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor;
}

var isPreviewMode = function() { 
    return typeof Sitecore !== "undefined" && !isEditMode()
}

var isNormalMode = function() { 
    return typeof Sitecore === "undefined"
}
```

```
if (isEditMode ()){
    // runs if page is in edit mode
}

if (isPreviewMode()){
    // runs if page is in preview mode
}

if (isNormalmode()){
    // runs if page is in normal mode
}
```

Vlad's answer returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: Sitecore is not defined` if Sitecore doesn't exist.

Other Dan's answer relies on a css class which is unneeded for detection, but is useful for .